# collapse and expanded tree

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

i am so new in javascript.i made a tree in mvc.here is the code.

```
      @helper TreeView(treeview.Models.PatientSubTree patientTree)
{

        if (patientTree.subTrees.Where(s => s.parentID ==     patientTree.Seed).Any())
        {
            foreach (var node in patientTree.subTrees)
            {
                    <li>
                        @if (node.parentID == patientTree.Seed)
                            {
                                treeview.Models.PatientSubTree inner = new   treeview.Models.PatientSubTree { Seed = node.ID, subTrees = patientTree.subTrees };
                                @*<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span*@ 

                                                        <a href="#" onclick="navigate('@node.Path');">@node.Text</a>
                                    if (node.HasChild)
                                    {
                                                <ul>
                                                    @TreeView(inner)
                                                </ul>
                                            }

                                 }
                    </li>
            }

          }
    }
```

and for having expanded and collapsed tree ,i added this java script code which you can see below. at first i add a 'handle' class to each
node and then i will add collapse expanded on it.But after applying this codes my tree is not displayed properly...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubDuR.png)

in the image u can see that 'fff' and 'ggg' must be in a same level because they are both children of 'eee' . 'ccc' seems to be the child of 'bbb' but it also must be in the same level as 'bbb'.Because both 'bbb' and 'ccc' are children of 'aaa'....

i dont know why java script code does not work properly.

```
 $(document).ready(function () { jQuery("#tree ul").hide();

   jQuery("#tree li").prepend("<span class='handle'></span>");

    jQuery("#tree li:has(ul)")
      .children(":first-child").addClass("collapsed")
      .click(function () {
          jQuery(this).toggleClass("collapsed expanded")
            .siblings("ul").toggle();
      });
});

  $(function () {
    $("ul#tree li").each(function () {
        as = $(this).children('a');
        if (!as.length) {  //
            $(this).hide();
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Hi its seems to be, this helper will be useful for http://matthidinger.com/archive/2011/11/27/Writing-a-Fluent-ASP-NET-MVC-Recursive-TreeView-Helper/  . if you want you can use this easily thanks karthik